# mongodb - unique field allover documents of collection

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I want to add validation of a unique field (product slug) among all the documents of the collection.

If the user adds a new product and slug of that new product already available in MongoDB then it should give me an error. I have experience in MySQL. If I make that field unique it will give me an error. So, How could I implement such kind of functionality using MongoDB validator?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: if you already tried making it unique similar to my answer, what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the field.

Something like

```
db.products.createIndex({"slug": 1}, { "unique": true})
```

Comment: found this solution on the same URL and also implemented before your answer. thank you for your response.